# How to render a 3D brain image in a mayavi plot

Tags: python, graph, rendering, mayavi, neuroscience

I have to plot a networks of connections of brain regions. I would like obtaining something similar to *Figure 1*.

[image: Figure 1]

I was able to put points in a 3D space and link them with edge by using python with mayavi. The code is here:

```
import mayavi    

# get data
xyz = getCoords(file_coords)
communities = getCommunities(file_communities)    

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
mlab.clf()

# plot points
pts = mlab.points3d(xyz[:,0], xyz[:,1], xyz[:,2],
                    communities,
                    colormap= "Blues",
                    scale_factor=7,
                    resolution=50)

# plot edges            
pts.mlab_source.dataset.lines = np.array(list_of_edges)
tube = mlab.pipeline.tube(pts, tube_radius=0.1)
mlab.pipeline.surface(tube, color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

mlab.show()
```

You can see the output of the code here, *in Figure 2* :

(Do not consider the arrow and the curve on the top side, because they were just a try to create a sort of orientation)
[image: Figure 2]

How can I create a 3D brain rendering in order to obtain something similar to *Figure 1*:

Comment: did you figured this out?